# LINQ "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected" (NOT temp tables)

Tags: sql-server, linq

Long-time lurker, first-time poster here :)

I've decided to ask here since I've grown tired of searching in Google, SO and such. I'm experiencing this error when importing a Stored Procedure from my SQL 2005 DB to my Website (FW 4.0, C#) LINQ project:

**"The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected"**

I have two queries. **I'd like to note that I'm not using temporary tables**. These queries have only been edited in variable names and such, for security measures. Anyways, here's the one that **works**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyWorkingProc]
@OS numeric
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql varchar(5000)

set @sql = '
        SELECT
        *
        FROM MYDB.dbo.MYVIEW 
        WHERE OS = ' + CONVERT(varchar, @OS)

EXEC('
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'', ''MYDB''; ''user''; ''password'', ''' + @sql + ''')')

END
```

And here's the one which **doesn't**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNotWorking]
@IDCLIENT int,
@PPNO char(10)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql varchar(5000)

set @sql = '
        SELECT
        *
        FROM MYDB.dbo.MYOTHERVIEW
        WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @IDCLIENT) + ' AND PASSPORTNO = ' + @PPNO + ' ORDER BY AGE'

EXEC('
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'', ''MYDB''; ''user''; ''password'', ''' + @sql + ''')')  

END
```

Here's what I've tried and found, along with a few notes and questions:

- Both users (LINQ and Remote Server) are db_owner.
- The non-working stored procedure works if I leave it with only one parameter (doesn't matter which one). If I add a new one, it doesn't work.
- If I make an empty SP with a simple select * from any table, and two or more parameters, it works (so it doesn't make sense).
- Let's say the problem is in EXEC. If so, how come the first SP works?. Ok, the problem isn't there then. (that's what logic tells me, I guess?)
- The problem is not the view, as it doesn't work if I use the view I access in the working SP.
- I need to do this using the queries provided. I can't use linked servers or anything similar as we need to do this to connect to 6.5 databases, and it doesn't solve or explain why the first SP works and the second one doesn't, while using the same method.
- I tried to add a parameter (taken from the non-working SP) to the working SP and it works, so it must be something with the second SP, but I dunno what :/
- Okay, if I modify the 2nd SP and remove the parameters in the style of @VAR and hardcode them into a single @sql variable, it works perfectly. So, I see it must be something with including variables into a dynamic query (or something).

I'm literally pulling my hair off, so any ideas and suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance!
- DARKGuy

Comment: Are these sql-server databases?  You could use linked servers instead of the dynamic queries.

Comment: Yes they are. I could, but in this case we can't as we're using this to connect to 6.5 databases. That's not the point though, as I've had that problem happen to queries made to tables/views in the same server and DB, but we just used another workaround, and that time it had to do with temp tables, this time doesn't :P

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by removing the dynamic parameters, hardcoding it to return some rows (by hardcoding the parameters, too) then adding it to LINQ and then editing the SP back to its original dynamic query with parameters and such. Damn, stupid LINQ bugs :(

Comment: If it makes you feel any better LINQ also gets tripped up on conditional results. :)

Comment: If @PPNO  is char(10) then shouldn't it be in quotes in the dynamic sql.

Comment: And shouldn't CONVERT(VARCHAR, @IDCLIENT) be something along the lines of CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @IDCLIENT)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ORM code generation tools such as those in `Linq2Sql` function imports usually run your SPROCs with the [SHOWPLAN_ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx) setting turned on, without actually executing the proc, in order to 'sniff' the result set.

This approach has limitations, as you've found, with dynamic SQL, and also often are issues with procs which use TempDB or have branches which return data with different schemas.

Your solution is a good one, i.e. to replace the real proc with one which is hard coded, but which returns mock data which is representative of the actual data.

**Edit**

Another pattern which I've seen to address this is to embed the hard coded 'schema' result into an uncallable condition, like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[someProc]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF (1 = 0)
    BEGIN
      -- "Cheat" the ORM resultset sniffing by returning an example of the schema.
      -- Casting and name aliasing to ensure the ORM derives the correct types
      SELECT CAST('Hello' AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Name, CAST (1 AS BIT) AS IsOnline, ...
      RETURN;
    END
    .. rest of the REAL proc goes here
```

Comment: It is a shame that even when I use [`with result sets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) with my dynamic SQL, Linq2Sql still fails to detect a resultset, and I have to repeat my columns from the `result sets` in this fashion as well. `sp_describe_first_result_set` understands `with result sets` just fine, but apparently Linq2Sql is not using it.

Answer (score 1):

I too had same issue. And solution was at http://developwith.net/2012/07/16/unknown-return-type-linq-to-sql/ Checking many sites says about those 3 points mentioned in this link but nowhere mentioned about transaction causing the problem. In my case, it was try catch block  raising the hell. After removing it, LINQ to SQL behaved normal. Later introduced the try catch back.

Answer (score 1):

Use below format for writing proc ..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME
@variableName nvarchar(150)
AS
IF 1=0 BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF
END
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM' ;
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Difference in above format is 

`IF 1=0 BEGIN
 SET FMTONLY OFF
END`

Which helps to solve this problem and determine the return type .