# Temporary Table vs. Table Variable - both don't work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I use SQL Server and Linq-to-SQL in my application.

I have to do a lot of database stuff and after a few hours work I have a stored procedure ready to run.

Sadly I use temporary tables in it (`#TempTable`) so Linq-to-SQL will give me an error for my return type (read about this e.g. here: [LINQ "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected" (NOT temp tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958888/linq-the-return-types-for-the-following-stored-procedures-could-not-be-detected)).

The only working solution for me is to switch to a table variable (`DECLARE @temptable table`) - but for this I found out it is not possible to use dynamic queries (which I do around 60% of my whole stored procedure).

Any ideas?

Comment: **Entity Framework** is excellent at detecting the return type of a stored procedure, and if needed automatically creating a suitable "complex type" for it ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem: I simply wrap my first Stored Procedure with temporary tables in a second Stored Procedure with a single select.
This is automaticly recognized with an auto genereated object in LinQ and I'm happy :)